# wordpress save multiple value from select item

Tags: wordpress, save, custom-post-type, meta-boxes, customcolumn

i've created a meta box with a multiple select item that takes its values from a custom post type.

```
add_action("add_meta_boxes", "palinsesto_box");

function palinsesto_box() {
add_meta_box("palinsesto-meta", "Speakers",   "palinsesto_manager_meta_options", "palinsesto",   "side");}

function palinsesto_manager_meta_options($post)
{
wp_nonce_field( 'radio_schedule', 'schedule_noncename' );
echo '<label for="speaker_id">';
_e("Speaker", 'speaker_id' );
echo '</label> ';
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'speaker');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
echo '<select name="speaker_id[]" id="speaker_id" multiple="multiple">';
foreach($loop->posts as $dj):
    if($dj->ID == get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'speaker_id', true ))
    {
        $select = 'selected';
    }else{
    $select = '';
}
echo '<option value="'.$dj->ID.'" '.$select.'>'.$dj->post_title.'</option>';
endforeach;
echo '</select>';
echo '<p>Tieni premuto CTRL per selezionare più speakers</p>';
}
```

this part works!Now i would save the selected values and display it in a custom column and here there is something worng.

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_palinsesto_manager_meta_options');
function save_palinsesto_manager_meta_options($post_id)
{global $post;
if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ){
    //if you remove this the sky will fall on your head.
    return;
}else{
    if( isset( $_POST['speaker_id'] ) ) {  
    update_post_meta( $post_id,'speaker_id', esc_attr( $_POST['speaker_id'] ) );  
}
}
}

add_filter('manage_palinsesto_posts_columns', 'columns_palinsesto');
function columns_palinsesto($old_columns)
{
$new_columns = array(
    'cb'     => '<input type="checkbox">',
    'img'    => 'Immagine',
    'title'  => __('Palinsesto'),
    'conduce' => 'Conduce',

);
return array_merge( $new_columns, $old_columns );
}

add_action('manage_palinsesto_posts_custom_column', 'get_palinsesto_columns',
10, 2);
function get_palinsesto_columns($col, $post_id)
{global $post;

$conduce=get_post_meta( $post_id,'speaker_id',$value );


switch($col) {
case 'img':
    if(has_post_thumbnail($post_id)) {
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id);
    } else {
        echo 'Nessuna immagine!';
    }
    break;
case 'conduce':

    echo $conduce;
    break;
}
}
```

This part of code only returns one value and displays the word array or numbers....can u help me????

Comment: Did you try the code?

Comment: Your code examples could use a little indentation to make them easier to read. Take care of your readers whom you ask for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise you to read:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_$post_type_posts_custom_column

The metabox, save and retrieve options i know it's working:

```
add_action("add_meta_boxes", "palinsesto_box");

function palinsesto_box() {
    add_meta_box("palinsesto-meta", "Speakers",   "palinsesto_manager_meta_options", "post", "side", 'high' );
}

function palinsesto_manager_meta_options( $post ) {

    wp_nonce_field( 'palinsesto_manager_meta_options', 'palinsesto_manager_meta_options_nonce' );

    echo '<label for="speaker_id">';
        _e("Speaker", 'speaker_id' );
    echo '</label> ';
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post');
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 


    $speaker_id_values = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_speaker_ids', true ); ?>

    <?php if ( $loop->have_posts() ): ?>

        <select name="speaker_id[]" id="speaker_id" multiple="multiple">

            <?php while( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post();  ?>
                <?php 
                    $selected = ( in_array( get_the_ID(), $speaker_id_values ) ) ? 'selected="selected"' :  '';
                ?>
                <option value="<?php the_ID() ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php the_title(); ?></option>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </select>

        <p>Tieni premuto CTRL per selezionare più speakers</p>

    <?php endif ?>

   <?php
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_palinsesto_manager_meta_options');
function save_palinsesto_manager_meta_options($post_id) {


    // Check if our nonce is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['palinsesto_manager_meta_options_nonce'] ) )
        return $post_id;

    $nonce = $_POST['palinsesto_manager_meta_options_nonce'];

    // Verify that the nonce is valid.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'palinsesto_manager_meta_options' ) )
        return $post_id;

    // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return $post_id;

    // Check the user's permissions.
  if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;

  } else {

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;

  }


    if ( isset( $_POST['speaker_id'] ) ) {

        $sanitized_data = array();

        $data = (array) $_POST['speaker_id'];

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

            $sanitized_data[ $key ] = (int)strip_tags( stripslashes( $value ) );

        }

        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_speaker_ids', $sanitized_data );

    }

}
```

But the custom columns I didn't test it.

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-speaker_columns', 'set_custom_edit_speaker_columns' );
add_action( 'manage_speaker_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_speaker_column', 10, 2 );

function set_custom_edit_speaker_columns($columns) {
    unset( $columns['author'] );
    $columns['speaker_id'] = __( 'Speaker', 'your_text_domain' );

    return $columns;
}

function custom_speaker_column( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {

        case 'speaker_id' :

            $speaker_ids = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_speaker_ids', true )

            if ( count( $speaker_ids ) > 0 ) {
                foreach ( $speaker_ids as $speaker_id ) {
                     echo get_the_title($speaker_id) . ' ';   
                }    
            } else {
                echo 'Nothing here';
            }

            break;

    }
}
```

You can improve the code.

Comment: the save option code works but the column always returns the word array

Comment: it works now you forgot a ';' after $speaker_ids = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_speaker_ids', true )

Comment: if i remove the speaker_id loop everything works i d0n't know why

Comment: I've tested it here, alone and with multiple metaboxes and it's working for me, all of them are being displayed here. Please edit your question and paste your code so we can try to find the error.